# Forms not submitting when using the include tag

Tags: django, django-forms, wagtail

I have created a Subscribe form in Wagtail Form Builder, when the form is submitted from its template subscribe_form.html, the submission goes through successfully.

```
<form action="{% pageurl page %}" method="POST">
     {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="shop-subscribe bg-color-green margin-bottom-40">
        <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8 md-margin-bottom-20">
                            <h2>Subscribase para mantenerse<strong> informado</strong></h2>
                    </div>




                    <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="input-group">


                             <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Correo Electronico..." {{ form.subscribase }}>
                                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                                            <button class="btn" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i></button>
                                    </span>

                            </div>

                                {{ form.subscribase.errors }}
                        </div>
                </div>
        </div><!--/end container-->
    </div>

 </form>
```

However, when I used the include tag to include it on other pages, it does not submit, and I don't get any error message.

```
{% include "home/subscribe_form.html" %}
```

Can someone please advise on what could be causing the form not to submit when using the include tag?

Comment: You can't include the template anywhere like that. The template has to be called with the appropriate context that has the `form`, `page` variables set, which would happen in the `Page` model that has the form.

Comment: What @solarissmoke said is correct. I suggest you create a template tag which initializes the form and page - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/

Comment: @solarissmoke, thank you for making clear the process needed to achieve this.

Comment: @dotcomly, thank you for pointing me the correct direction on how to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on what others have said, using a custom template tag for this is a simple way to do it. Inclusion tags allow you to call a template tag and pass args/kwargs to them, perform logic, and then render a template with that logic for inclusion in your rendered page.

In an app directory for your project create a folder, create a dir named `templatetags`, create an empty file within that named `__init__.py` (Django uses this to know the file should be run on startup), and then create another file in the new dir name `my_custom_tags.py` (or whatever you'd like to use). Within that-

```
from django.template import Library

register = Library()

@register.inclusion_tag("home/subscribe_form.html")
def subscription_form(form):
    return {'form':form}
```

Now, in your main template:

```
{% load my_custom_tags %}
{# (or whatever you named your file for custom tags #}

{# where you want to include your tag, pass the form from the main template; be sure to pass your form variable from your context data #}
{% subscription_form form %}
```

You have rendered your form. Since you are passing the form from context, any logic performed outside the template tag is still intact. This is especially useful when you have a generic template to use for elements in multiple places but need to perform logic outside of the view (or, in Wagtail's case, the Page/snippet logic embedded in the model).

Comment: very useful and detail explanation.